# Restrict Google Maps Directions API to specific city

Tags: javascript, google-directions-api

I'm using Google's Directions API to provide directions from a specific apartment in NY to some other place of their choosing.

```
var directionsService   =   new google.maps.DirectionsService();

directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: mode,
    transitOptions: {
        modes: [ 'SUBWAY' ]
    }
}, function(result, status) {
    if ( status === 'OK')
        directionsDisplay.setDirections( result);
});
```

Is there a way for me to restrict the directions provided to New York, and not any further?

**EDIT:** For some reason, my 'Hello everyone!' got cut off from the beginning of my question, sooo... Hello everyone! `goto question_start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took care of it reactively, by checking the result for a specific substring, which in my case looks like

`if (result.routes[0].legs[0].end_address.indexOf('New York') === -1) { //do stuff }`

If the user searches outside of NY, I open an `InfoWindow` warning them to restrict their search.

Answer (score 0):

In your code that takes the input you could check if the destination's latitude and longitude values are inside a geo-fence (by checking minimum and maximum values).

The waypoints in the result could be checked, if your destination input is not a `LatLng` (and you don't want to convert it to that).